# I made Unchangeable Modifications in my Stylesheet

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7O3i.jpg) [Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwZ4k.jpg) I made a modification in my WordPress site's stylesheet (style.css) where I wanted all links to be underlined. The code I added was:

```
a {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

This worked perfectly. Now, I need to modify the code so that the links are underlined only when hovering over them. So, I changed it to

```
a {
    text-decoration: none; /* No underline by default */
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

However, nothing changes.

Even after removing the code, there's no difference. To rule out caching issues, I made font color changes in another menu, and those changes are reflected perfectly when viewing the page in a different browser (with cache disabled). Why am I unable to remove the underline from links?

Comment: You probalby have other styles on `<a>` tags that override your second version of the styles, it's probably why your first version had `!important`. You should inspect one of the links in the developper console to see which styles apply, and which ones override. You can try with `!important` in your second version as a test, however important styles should be your last resort. It is preferred to have a more specific selector to override global styles, for example `body a { ... }` will take precedence to `a { ... }` even if declared first

Comment: I've searched through both of my stylesheets and found no additional rules for links.
Initially, the links weren't underlined. Then, I inserted the rule and they were. However, after removing the rule from the CSS stylesheet, it persists. When I inspect the link in the developer tools, it still appears there.

Comment: Links by default (with no CSS rule defined) appear underlined. If initially they were not underlined, there must be a rule somewhere. That's why I suggested you examine in developper tools, because you can see all styles applied and where they come from (either inline with a `style` attribute, shown in the "element" section, or it indicates the CSS file). Those styles probably don't come from your own CSS files, but from a plugin, bootstrap etc. If you are not familiar with developper tools, comment out your own rules for links and inspect a link. Don't hesitate to post an image of the styles

Comment: Sorry I hadn't seen you had already added screen captures. You can see in the first picture that other files affect the styling of the links `typography.css`, `materialize.css.min` etc. They are likely added to the page after your styles, so that they override your links styles. Those are the ones you want to override. Try to declare your styles with more specific rules such as `body a { ... }` and `body a:hover { ... }` and tell me if this works

Comment: i found it! After so many hours, finally. Thank you very much for the help!
There was a single rules under Customizer: additional CSS. Now the underline is gone, and I can try hovering over it. I will take that into account with the body {...}!

Answer (score 0):

There was a single rules under Customizer: additional CSS. So not in the stylesheet but in the Theme Customizer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).